# Best way to open,crop,rotate and convert a windowsbitmap (bmp)

Tags: php, image-processing

I like to open a Windows bitmap file within php.

I found some piece of code (imagecreatefrombmp), that converts a bmp to png.
But that code is in plain php and to slow. 
My images have a size around 1000x2000 pixels.

gdlib doesn't open bmp files.

IMagick to complicated to compile and i don't find windows binaries that work with my php.

Additional i like to open that bmp from a string.
it is streamed from a db.

I also need to do some rotations (0, 90, 180, 270) and some cropping.

Finally i like to save it to tiff or png file (or string).

But primary problem, how to open a bmp file?

plattform:

- php 5.2 (vc6,ts) on Windows Cli and Apache 2.2 Module
- zend framework 1.10

Comment: that is not a php way. maybe exec is blocked by suhosin.
if nothing helps: i will write my own extension which is doing my business case.

Answer (score 0):

You can find precompiled gmagick PHP extension for Windows at valokuva site. The file is named php_gmagick_ts.dll.

The trick is that these are built using VC9 compiler so you will need VC9 version of Apache and PHP as well. If you plan to install PHP as a module, you will need a thread safe (ts) version of gmagick and PHP. You can get Apache built using VC9 from apachelounge, file named httpd-2.2.14-win32-x86-ssl.zip and PHP from PHP web site, file named php-5.3.1-Win32-VC9-x86.msi

gmagick code samples are available in the PHP documentation or in great tutorial at Zend DevZone.

To see all links for this answer go to http://www.google.com/notebook/public/11284522948259357138/BDQo5QwoQqbC67p4i

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, if you do not want to compile it from PECL, you will need to update your stack to 5.3/vc9.